# Как можно заменять нечитабельные символы?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, функции, символы

у меня есть текст например: "ЌŘĮŜŤÃĹЌĮĹĹ",мне нужно чтобы код перевёл его в "Kristalkill",можно ли как-то это сделать без ввода вручную символов жсон,и подальшим реплейсом,или если есть уже готовая база с такими символами(Которую можно скачать)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ваша строчка состоит из букв с диакритиками, причём диакритики не отдельно от букв, а объединённые в один символ. Чтобы оставить буквы, нужно два шага:

1. Декомпозиция (отделение букв и диакритик) при помощи [`String.prototype.normalize()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/normalize).
2. Удаление небуквенных символов при помощи [Unicode Property Escapes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Unicode_Property_Escapes).

Потом уже можно заняться исправлением регистра.

(UPD: добавлено сохранение цифр и эмодзи, см. комментарии)

```js
const str = "ЌŘĮŜŤÃĹЌĮĹĹ123\u{231A}\u{2194}\u{FE0F}\u{1F469}\u{1F469}\u{1F3FF}";
console.log(str);

const cleaned = str
  .normalize("NFD")
  .replace(/[^\p{Letter}\p{Number}\p{Emoji_Modifier_Base}\p{Emoji_Modifier}\p{Emoji_Presentation}\p{Emoji}\uFE0F]/gu, '');
console.log(cleaned);

const name = cleaned[0].toUpperCase() + cleaned.slice(1).toLowerCase();
console.log(name);
```

Comment: А например с ķó⍑ будет работать?

Comment: С первыми двумя буквами должно, но последняя только похожа на букву, поэтому удалится: https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2351/index.htm

Comment: Ок,спасибо большое

Comment: Можно ли как-то сделать  чтобы цифры и эмоции не чистились,и если для этого нужна база  то я её нашёл

Comment: Огромное спасибо вам

Comment: Номера добавить легко, но с емодзи будет чуть труднее. Я изменил регулярное выражение, но для понимания нужно ознакомиться с https://github.com/tc39/proposal-regexp-unicode-property-escapes#matching-emoji

Comment: А возможно исключить определенные символы по типу < и :

Comment: С смысле сохранить в строке ещё и символы `<` и `:`? Если так, добавьте их просто в конец набора сохраняемых символов между `\uFE0F` и `]`.

Comment: Ок,спасибо ещё раз огромное